# how to install install.packages("prob") in Jupyter notebook

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, package

I wanted to use Jupyter Notebook to do my homework. But when I put `install.packages("prob")` in Jupyter Notebook, it gave me this error:

Warning message:
“package ‘prob’ is not available (for R version 3.4.2)”

when I typed `library(prob)`, it said no package called 'prob'

> Error in library(prob): there is no package called ‘prob’
>   Traceback:
>
> 1. library(prob)
> 2. stop(txt, domain = NA)

anyone knows how to fix this problem? I would be very appreciate it.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you can't install that package is exactly what it says it is :)

```
"Warning message: "package 'prob' is not available (for R version 3.4.2)"
```

If you [look up the package on CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/prob/index.html) it will tell you:

> Package ‘prob’ was removed from the CRAN repository.
>   Formerly available versions can be obtained from the archive.
>   Archived on 2017-09-11 as it depends on 'fAsianOptions', which was archived.

As that says, there are  archived versions. But, to be clear, you'll need an archived version of 'fAsianOptions' as well.

To install an archived package, use:

```
archived_package = "a character vector with a URL or path to file you've downloaded"
install.packages(pkg = archived_package, repos = NULL)
```

I'd advise downloading the file yourself and then using the character vector of a path to that file as your pkg argument, unless you're familiar with the various quirks of downloading a file  as part of a call to a function.